# Best way to display column as row on gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I changed a gridview display from:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C   Graph
Value A    1          9          Chart A
Value B    3          7          Chart B
```

...to this:

```
Column A   Column B   Column C
Value A    1          9
        Chart A (colspan = 3)
Value B    3          7
        Chart B (colspan = 3)
```

The Graph A and B display was accomplished by the following code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td colspan=3>
           <asp:Chart ID="ImgChart" runat="server"... />   
        </td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

It works ok, and does what I want but the resulting HTML is this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Column A</td>
      <td>Column B</td>
      <td>Column C</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value A</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
         <image...>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Value B</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
         <image...>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This results on an empty td that has a annoying width that I am not able to control and it would be nice if it didn't exist...

What are your suggestions?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't achieve this with the GridView. Try to use the ListView control. It provide more flexibility with resulting layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use PIVOT in the Stored procedure and Bind the datatable with the GridView.

Comment: Can you explain it further please

Comment: Have a look at it: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/05/22/sql-server-pivot-table-example/

Comment: I understand what you mean but I don't think it can be applied on this case. I now realised that I didn't format the end result table

Comment: Ok edited the resultut table I want and changed the graph terms to chart because that information trully is a chart.